# Using Proxy Authorization Header with ScalajHTTP

Tags: scala, http, proxy

I'm getting a 407 error using scalajHTTP. I read through the repository and it seems like I should be able to pass the basic auth credentials as a base64 encoded value. I've also tried using the helper method described in the GitHub issues .proxyAuth but that is no longer part of HTTPRequest in ScalaJ according to error messages (as well as it not being in the documentation)

Any ideas? My endpoint URL is HTTPS as well as my proxy (for additional context)

```
 val proxyHost= s"https://$forwardProxy"
 val requestForward = Http(url).postData(redactedSecret)
   .option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL)
   .headers(("Content-Type", "application/json"), ("Proxy-Authorization", s"Basic $proxyAuth"))
   .proxy(proxyHost, 8080).asString
 val responseForward: HttpResponse[String] = requestForward
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issued posted in Github but still not resolved, https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. I researched around and after trying http client libraries, I kept getting 407 errors even though they all support proxy auth. Anyway, I ended up having to do the following.

add

```
import java.net.{Authenticator,PasswordAuthentication}
```

and the modified code body that I previously above looks like:

```
val requestForward: HttpRequest = Http(url).postData(data)
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.proxy(proxyHost, 8080)
.option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL)
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
 override def getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication = {
  new PasswordAuthentication( s"$username", s"$password".toCharArray())
 }
})
```

So as you can see I removed the header from the original request object and instead overrode the credentials. Make sure you do this before you call on the response object.